# Why does Yii render "<?php" into every backend controller output?

Tags: php, yii

#### Reproduceable problem

In 2.0.3 "advanced" (Yii offers basic and advanced setup of a project) create an empty controller in the backend, like

```
public function actionTest()
{
}
```

and call it in the browser. You'll see an empty page. When looking at the source code, you'll see a lonely php tag.

```
<?php
```

This looks like a bug to me, as it does not happen in the frontend folder, just in backend folder. This is critical when you render out CSV files or so, it will break the file.

I'm unsure if this is a bug on my side or a real bug inside the framework.

Comment: Maybe you have an output of `<?php` (something like: `echo "<?php"` - which you've added in mistake of course) in a global function that runs before the execution of the `actionTest` function?

Comment: Maybe you try use `<?php` in HTML file? And yes, it looks like a bug... from your side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This is a bug in Yii 2.0.3!

... caused by a lower-level and not-so-obvious whitespace problem in naked PHP files.

#### Tickets & more information:

https://github.com/githubjeka/yii2-rest/issues/3

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/issues/24

http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php#116883

#### How to fix this:

The problem in a nutshell: A PHP tag is `<?php[whitespace character]`, not just `<?php`. Holy! Totally makes sense, but let's be honest, who would have known this instantly ?

Yii 2.x uses (in the advanced demo application) the "empty" file *config/bootstrap.php*, just containing a php tag `<?php` WITHOUT a whitespace directly after. When bootstrap.php is now loaded via index.php it is loaded as a text file containing `<?php`, not parsed as a PHP file.

You can fix this by simply added a whitespace directly after the tag.